# UTF-8 encoding in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, utf-8, character-encoding

**MvcConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{



       @Bean
        public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }
    }
```

**jsp:**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    </head>
    <body class="nav-md">
     <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="fluxDomaine" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" >
                        <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
                <div class="item form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="INDCTR_DS">INDCTR DS </label>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <form:input type="text" path="INDCTR_DS" id="INDCTR_DS" name="INDCTR_DS" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"/>
                           </div>
                            <form:errors path="INDCTR_DS" cssClass="alerttt" />
                          </div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add"/>

</form:form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i'm facing a problem with encoding , for example if i save a "**à**" it becomes "**Ã** " and "**é**" becomes "**Ã©**", and when i try to manually save it in my mysql DB its saving proprely.

Thanks for any advices..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special characters issue, i replaced :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

by

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

and i was able to persist special characters as i want..

Answer (score 1):

I used to get this trouble while working with Spring MVC too.
Just followed this article: http://fazlansabar.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-enable-utf-8-support-on-tomcat.html and it's worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a `SpringCharacterEncoding` filter . Simply add below lines to the `web.xml` in your Spring MVC project .This will enforce UTF-8 encoding strictly in your code.

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Which server are you using, Tomcat?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I also changed server.xml and added utf8 to Connector definition.